# GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found during getting user list of enterprise

Tags: java, google-api, google-api-java-client

I'm writing with Google Play EMM API (lib google-api-services-androidenterprise-v1-rev8-1.20.0.jar) simple application that should generate activation code for automatic installation of Device Policy Controller (Android for Work) on device.

```
HttpTransport sHttpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
JsonFactory sJsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

GoogleCredential credentials = new GoogleCredential.Builder().setTransport(sHttpTransport).setJsonFactory(sJsonFactory)
        .setServiceAccountId(MASTER_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)
        .setServiceAccountScopes(AndroidEnterpriseScopes.all())
        .setServiceAccountPrivateKeyFromP12File(new File(PRIVATE_KEY_P12_FILE_NAME))
        .build();

AndroidEnterprise sAndroidEnterprise = new AndroidEnterprise(sHttpTransport, sJsonFactory, credentials);

String userId = sAndroidEnterprise.users().list(enterpriseId, userEmail).execute()
            .getUser()
            .get(0)
            .getId();

String activationCode = sAndroidEnterprise.users().generateToken(enterpriseId, userId).execute().getToken();
```

The problem is that I get exception as result in method execute() in

```
String userId = sAndroidEnterprise.users().list(enterpriseId, userEmail).execute()

com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 404 Not Found
{
  "code" : 404,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "enterpriseId",
    "locationType" : "parameter",
    "message" : "No enterprise was found for the given id.",
    "reason" : "notFound"
  } ],
  "message" : "No enterprise was found for the given id."
}
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:321)
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1056)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:419)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:352)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:469)
```

The most interesting thing that if I put nonexistent e-mail as parameter userEmail there is no exception in method execute(), of course method getUser() returns null.

How to fix this code to get successfully user ID?
For me it looks like it's library's or server's problem, but I hope I'm just doing something wrong.

Please note: I already enrolled a customer successfully and did preparation according https://developers.google.com/play/enterprise/samples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are invoking the users() method with authentication using MSA account. Try authentication using ESA account i.e. the enterprise id you are mentioning in the request. ( you need to have service account created for customer to be able to authenticate). Problem will get resolved.